# Making multiple ajax requests synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

Let's suppose I have some function called `makeRequest()`, which makes an AJAX request to a server.

Now let's suppose I am given the amount of times this request should be made, but I can't do them asynchronously but synchronously instead.

For instance, I am given the number 5, and I shall call `makeRequest()`, when it's done, I shall call it again, and when it's done, I shall call it again... I should end up calling it 5 times.

I'm no expert at JavaScript but I found it easy to handle asynchronous calls by the use of callbacks.

So, my `makeRequest()` function takes a `callback` argument that is to be executed when the request has succeeded.

In my previous example, I had to make the request 5 times, so the behaviour should look like:

```
makeRequest(function () {
     makeRequest(function () {
        makeRequest(function () {
           makeRequest(function () {
              makeRequest(function () {
              });
           });
        });
     });
});
```

How can I design this to behave the same for **any** argument given to me, be it 6, 12 or even 1?

**PS:** I have tried many approaches, the most common involving creating while loops that wait until a flag is set by a finished request. All of these approaches makes the browser think the script crashed and prompt the user to stop the script.

Comment: Have you tried calling the function again in success handler function of the previous one.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, recursively call the ajax request, while keeping track of a count variable:

```
function makeRequest(count, finalCallback){
    someAjaxCall(data, function(){
        if(count > 1){
            makeRequest(count - 1, finalCallback);
        } else {
            finalCallback && finalCallback();
        }
    });
}
```

`finalCallback` is a optional callback (function) that will be executed when all the requests are completed.

Comment: This is pretty nice! What if `makeRequest` should receive a callback function from a caller, which is to be executed when all the N requests have been made?

Comment: @MatiCicero: I added an optional `finally` callback you can do that with :-)

Comment: ... but I forgot that `finally` is a reserved name in JS, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way,

```
var i = 5;  // number of calls to you function calling ajax
recurs(i);  // call it initially

function recurs(count) {


  makeRequest(function() {
    count--;  // decrement count
    if (count > 1) {
      recurs(count)  // call function agian
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: @blex.. sorry.. was in hurry

Comment: So, I want to make 2 requests: `recurs(2)`, that will actually fire the request 3 times, now.

Comment: @Cerbrus.. I  was in real hurry i guess.. competing you :p

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written multiple Ajax calls using promises. This function will run synchronously. You can get the current position of response which is executed from Ajax.

```
var ajaxs = {
    i : 0,
    callback : null,
    param : null,
    exec_fun : function (i) {
        let data_send = this.param[i];
        let url = this.url;
        this.promise = new Promise(function (res,rej) {
              $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: data_send,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(resvalidate){
                            res(resvalidate);
                        }
                });

        });
        this.promise.then(function (resvalidate) {
            let resp = resvalidate,
                param = ajaxs.param,
                pos = ajaxs.i,
                callback_fun = ajaxs.callback_fun;
            callback_fun(resp,ajaxs.i);
            ajaxs.i++;
            if( ajaxs.param[ajaxs.i] != undefined){
                ajaxs.exec_fun(ajaxs.i);
            }
        });


    },
    each : function (url,data,inc_callback) {
        this.callback_fun = inc_callback;
        this.param = data;
        this.url = url;

        this.exec_fun(ajaxs.i);


    }
};


let url = "http://localhost/dev/test_ajax.php";
let data_param = [{data : 3},{data : 1},{data : 2}];

ajaxs.each(url,data_param, function (resp,i) {
    console.log(resp,i);

});
```

Comment: Add the ajaxs object and then call it by **ajaxs.each(...);**